# What is the equivalent code in C# of the Vb 'Type'

Tags: c#, vb6

I have an old system in `VB6`, now I'm trying to build a new one using `C#`.

I have this VB6 Code:

```
Private Type T_Parameters

   Name        As String * 16  (What is this ? '* 16')
   YearsOld    As Byte
   Day         As Byte

End Type
```

What would be the equivalent code in `C#` ? What is this `Type` ?

Comment: Never ever is this VB 6.0 code.

Comment: Yes, it is ! @Tomalak

Comment: Thanks @MyCodeSucks. It's called `Struct`then...

Comment: No, it isn't. There are no curly braces in VB 6.0, there never have been.

Comment: Obs: The comment of MyCodeSucks proves that you are wrong @Tomalak ... Just a little missunderstanding.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro: Tomalak is right. There are no curly braces in VB6. VB.NET, maybe. But not VB6.

Comment: @Tomalak So tell me, how this is working using pure Visual Basic 6 ? Anyway, `MyCodeSUcks` understood and solved me the problem, thanks !

Comment: VB.NET does not use curly braces either where c# uses `[index]` for example vb.net uses '(index)' as an example

Comment: @MyCodeSucks So , why this code is in the VisualBasic6 ? Could you solve that to me aswell ? Thanks

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro: It's possible it could still work, but braces aren't required in VB6.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Those are square, not curly braces. VB.NET actually *does* use curly braces, just not in the context of OP’s code (they are used for aggregate initialisers instead). Likewise, VB.NET uses square braces, but again in a *very* different context from C# (namely to use an otherwise reserved word as an identifier).

Comment: @MyCodeSucks No, that definitely doesn’t work. The code simply isn’t valid VB6. Now that PlayHardGoPro has updated the code, it’s valid VB.

Comment: I am aware of that I was looking at it from the context of `Methods function's Procedures, etc.. as an example.. but not a big deal because VB Sucks in my opinion

Answer (score 4):

It's been a long time since I've looked at VB 6 code, but I believe that's a fixed-length string. .NET doesn't support fixed-length strings, but you can come close with a `char[]`. I believe the C# equivalent would be:

```
private class T_Parameters
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public byte YearsOld { get; set; } 
    public byte Day { get; set; } 
}
```

Or possibly this, which would prevent the user from changing the size of the `Name` field:

```
private class T_Parameters
{
    public char[] Name { get; private set; } 
    public byte YearsOld { get; set; } 
    public byte Day { get; set; } 

    public T_Parameters() {
        Name = new String(' ', 16).ToCharArray();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
private class T_Parameters
{
    private string name = new String(' ', 16);

    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value.PadRight(16, ' ').Substring(0, 16); }
    }

    public byte YearsOld { get; set; } 
    public byte Day { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, `String * 16` allocates a fixed length string of 16 characters and initializes it with all spaces. Assigning longer values to such a string does not result in an error, but the value will be cut off.

Comment: @Tomalak So I suppose the closest equivalent would be `new String(' ', 16).ToCharArray()` instead of `new char[16]`?

Comment: @pswg If you need spaces as the default contents, then yes.

Comment: Since VB.NET does not support fixed length strings just limit the length of the string to 16.  Since the original code would not generate an error, just cut the length of the string off, after 16 characters.  Saves you from having to use a char array and convert it to a string unless you other example does exactly that?  I have never seen a string declared with a length before.

Comment: @Ramhound It's just a plain old `string`, but the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) is just a hand for 16 spaces, but yes the setter trims the value without causing any error.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - So basically exactly what I was thinking :$

Comment: +1 but a VB6 Type acts like a C# struct, not a class. It's analogous to a .Net value type.

Comment: @MarkJ structs in .NET should be immutable, but my understanding is that this is not the case with VB6 types (I could be wrong, like I said it's be a *long* time). So if it's actually used as a mutable type in VB6, wouldn't we need an analogously mutable type in .NET--i.e. a class?

Answer (score 2):

Make it a `struct`, like this:

```
private struct T_Parameters
{
    string Name;
    byte YearsOld;
    byte Day;
}
```

Or a `class`, like this:

```
public class T_Parameters
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte YearsOld { get; set }
    public byte Day { get; set; }
}
```

How to decide between `class` or `struct`?

Choose `struct`, if:

1. The object is small
2. The values are going to be immutable (read: not changing)
3. You have lots of objects

Otherwise, choose `class`.

Comment: I tried use struct, but I'm not able to get the values like:

`T_Parameters param = new T_Parameters  
param.Name` Why?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to build a struct?

```
private struct T_Parameters
{
    string Name;
    byte YearsOld;
    byte Day;
}
```